# C Program that finds the sum of each row and column of two separate 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

so what I'm trying to do is create a C program where the code creates 2 different 2D arrays filled in with random numbers from 100 - 1500 and I'm trying to incorporate a feature where the program will print out a 1D array containing the sum of corresponding rows in arrayA and arrayB,

I've already added in a feature where it finds the sum of each corresponding cell in the two arrays and prints them out

But I just can't seem to figure out how to find the sum of each row, my initial approach was in my function sumRow and I was initially going to simply add my product array to itself but I realised that it would only add each corresponding cell, not the row itself

```
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      {
         sumRows[i][j] = sumArray[i][j] + sumArray[i][j];
         printf("%d\t", sumRows[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\t]\n");
   }
}
```

As of right now, I've got an idea where if in my sumRow function I could simply add all of the contents together and print them out, that would automatically create a 1D array for both the rows and columns but I'm not so sure how to do this anymore

Any help and tips would be so so appreciated, thank you!

Here's my full working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 20

void randArray(int rows, int columns, int array[rows][columns]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
         array[i][j] = rand()%1400 +101;
         printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
      }
      printf("]\n");
   }
}

void product(int rows, int columns, int array1[rows][columns], int array2[rows][columns], int productArray[rows][columns]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
         productArray[i][j] =array1[i][j]*array2[i][j];
         printf("%d\t", productArray[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\t]\n");
   }
   
}

void sum(int rows, int columns, int array1[rows][columns], int array2[rows][columns], int sumArray[rows][columns])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      {
         sumArray[i][j] = array1[i][j] + array2[i][j];
         printf("%d\t", sumArray[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\t]\n");
   }
}

void sumRow(int rows, int columns, int sumArray[rows][columns], int sumRows[rows][columns]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      {
         sumRows[i][j] = sumArray[i][j] + sumArray[i][j];
         printf("%d\t", sumRows[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\t]\n");
   }
}

int main() {
   int rows = 0;                     //Variable to store the number of rows
   int columns = 0;                  //Variable to store the number of columns
   int arrayA[20][20];               //A 20x20 2D array A declaration which will be modified later on
   int arrayB[20][20];               //A 20x20 2D array B declaration which will be modified later on
   int productArray[20][20];
   int sumArray[20][20];
   int sumRows[20][20];
   int sumCols[20][20];

   printf("How many rows and columns would you like in the arrays?\n\nPlease enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d", &rows);
   printf("Please enter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d", &columns);

   //This wil both generate the random numbers and print out the arrays
   printf("Your arrays are:\nArray A:\n");
   randArray(rows, columns, arrayA);
   printf("ArrayB\n");
   randArray(rows, columns, arrayB);


   printf("The array containing the product of both arrays is:\n");
   product(rows, columns, arrayA, arrayB, productArray);

   printf("The array containing the sum of both arrays is:\n");
   sum(rows, columns, arrayA, arrayB, sumArray);

   printf("The array containing the sum rows of both arrays is:\n");
   sumRow(rows, columns, sumArray, sumRows);

   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You calculate the sum of corresponding _cells_, not rows.

Comment: But I believe you want `sumRows[i] = sumArrayA[i][j] + sumArrayB[i][j];`

Comment: Hi Paul, thats what I'm trying to do in my function but for some reason, it's just refusing to work with me, I've calculated the sum corresponding cells and I was originally trying to use this by just adding up the rows in that array but its not working even when I tried ```sumRows[i] = array1[i][j] +array2[i][j];```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using VLA arrays as arguments while passing non-VLA objects to those arguments.

The function thinks that the stride of each array is `columns`, while it is actually 20. Moreover, it becomes extremely risky when `rows * lows` is larger than `20 * 20` due to possible ... stack overflows.

One way to fix the issue is first parsing `rows` and `columns` followed by creating arrays with syntax:

```
int ARRAY[rows][columns];
```

Moreover, the function `sumRows()` looks suspicious.
A sum of rows of the matrix is actually a vector.
I guess that your intention was cumulative sum along columns.

The correct code may look like this:

```
void sumRow(int rows, int columns, int sumArray[rows][columns], int sumRows[rows][columns]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
      int cumsum = 0;
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
         cumsum += sumArray[i][j];
         sumRows[i][j] = cumsum;
         printf("%d\t", sumRows[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\t]\n");
   }
}
```

or

```
void sumRow(int rows, int columns, int sumArray[rows][columns], int sumRows[rows]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      int sum = 0;
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
         sum += sumArray[i][j];
      sumRows[i] = sum;
      printf("%d\n", sumRows[i]);
   }
}

...

int sumRows[rows];
sumRow(rows, columns, sumArray, sumRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sumRows as 1D array: int sumRows[rows];

```
void sumRow(int rows, int columns, int sumArray[rows][columns], int sumRows[rows]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
      printf("\t[\t");
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      {
         sumRows[i] += sumArray[i][j];
      }
      printf("%d\t", sumRows[i]);
      printf("\t]\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Write a program to add two dimensional arrays. Program should accept a limit of array and two 2D arrays and display its sum.**

#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

```
int a1[100][100],a2[100][100],sum[100][100];
int limit,i,j;

printf("ENTER THE LIMIT OF ARRAY : ");
scanf("%d",&limit);

printf("\nENTER THE VALUES OF ARRAY ONE : \n");
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
    for(j=0;j<limit;j++){
        scanf("%d",&a1[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\nENTER THE VALUES FOR ARRAY TWO : \n");
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
    for(j=0;j<limit;j++){
        scanf("%d",&a2[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\nENTERED VALUES FOR ARRAY ONE ARE\n\n");
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
    for(j=0;j<limit;j++){
        printf("%d\t",a1[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\nENTERED VALUES FOR ARRAY TWO ARE\n\n");
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
    for(j=0;j<limit;j++){
        printf("%d\t",a2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
    for(j=0;j<limit;j++){
        sum[i][j]=a1[i][j]+a2[i][j];
    }
}

printf("\n\nSUM OF TWO ARRAYS ARE \n\n");
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
    for(j=0;j<limit;j++){
        printf("%d\t",sum[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

[OUTPUT SCREENSHOT]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF24F.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)